# execute process from given directory with Groovy

Tags: groovy

How can I execute a process from a given directory.

I need to:

- Create a temp dir

> final File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", Long.toString(System.nanoTime())).mkdir();

- init a git directory in it

> "git init".execute()

Comment: What have you tried? Have you tried http://www.groovyexamples.org/2010/06/01/create-a-directory/ followed by http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/lang/String.html#execute%28java.util.List,%20java.io.File%29

Comment: You need the version of execute that takes a folder (for the working directory)

Comment: Another pointer http://groovy.329449.n5.nabble.com/Process-execute-in-working-dir-td337822.html